# convert from AngularJs to Angular 2+

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm new to Angular, and I have a task to convert AngularJs to Angular 8.

Can someone tell me what is ng-scope, ng-pristine, ng-form-valid ... ? And what is its equivalent in Angular 8?

Comment: Begin here: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade other than this question is really unsolvable that easily. It's not going to be simple and if you're left with that on your own - ask your employer for help right away, this is going to be though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS and Angular 2+ has night and day difference in many aspects. Many capabilities of the former is internally handled by the latter that you don't have to worry about them at all.

Take for instance `ng-pristine` and `ng-form-valid`. In angular 2+, you can use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and get away with it by calling the form control's properties.

```
<input formControlName="myForm" />
<span *ngIf="(myForm.dirty || myForm.touched) && myForm.invalid && myForm.errors.required">
  Mobile is required.
</span>
```

As for ng-scope, you don't even have to worry about it at all.

Angular.io has documentation on the upgrade from AngularJS to Angular 2+ which can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade). Then there is [ngMigration forum](https://github.com/angular/ngMigration-Forum/wiki), [ngMigration assistant](https://github.com/ellamaolson/ngMigration-Assistant) etc.

At the end of the day, the process is strictly your application dependent.